# ArrayAdapter IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android

I'm trying to remove an item from listview by onclick action. But i'm getting arrayindexoutofbound exception. I deleted item from 11 size array, but it still trying to get 11. item.

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            data.remove(getItemIndexByID(filteredData.get(position).getID()));
            filteredData.remove(position);      
            notifyDataSetChanged();

            flipMenu(lastHolder, 1);
            showPopup("Item Deleted"); 


        }
```

LOG:

```
    11-26 17:16:32.159: E/AndroidRuntime(26991): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-26 17:16:32.159: E/AndroidRuntime(26991): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 10, size is 10
11-26 17:16:32.159: E/AndroidRuntime(26991):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
11-26 17:16:32.159: E/AndroidRuntime(26991):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
11-26 17:16:32.159: E/AndroidRuntime(26991):    at com.innovationbox.passlocker.adapters.ListViewAdapter.getView(ListViewAdapter.java:100)
11-26 17:16:32.159: E/AndroidRuntime(26991):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2143)
11-26 17:16:32.159: E/AndroidRuntime(26991):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
11-26 17:16:32.159: E/AndroidRuntime(26991):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
11-26 17:16:32.159: E/AndroidRuntime(26991):    at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:638)
11-26 17:16:32.159: E/AndroidRuntime(26991):    at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4930)
11-26 17:16:32.159: E/AndroidRuntime(26991):    at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4087)
11-26 17:16:32.159: E/AndroidRuntime(26991):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
11-26 17:16:32.159: E/AndroidRuntime(26991):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
11-26 17:16:32.159: E/AndroidRuntime(26991):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:531)
11-26 17:16:32.159: E/AndroidRuntime(26991):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
11-26 17:16:32.159: E/AndroidRuntime(26991):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
11-26 17:16:32.159: E/AndroidRuntime(26991):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-26 17:16:32.159: E/AndroidRuntime(26991):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-26 17:16:32.159: E/AndroidRuntime(26991):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
11-26 17:16:32.159: E/AndroidRuntime(26991):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 17:16:32.159: E/AndroidRuntime(26991):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-26 17:16:32.159: E/AndroidRuntime(26991):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-26 17:16:32.159: E/AndroidRuntime(26991):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-26 17:16:32.159: E/AndroidRuntime(26991):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: from where `position` comes ?

Comment: `position` seems to be wrong the second time around. Is it updated properly?

Comment: position is here;    @Override
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)

Comment: onclick method is in getView method.i'm using getView's position value

Comment: How is data declared? If you have a `List<Integer>` descendant, it utterly confuses the `List.remove` method.

Comment: data declared like this: ArrayList<userPass> data = new ArrayList<userPass>();

Comment: can u post more code. I mean listview code completely. Do you have a getItem method??

Comment: It seems problem is on "filteredData.get(position)". "Invalid index 10, size is 10" means you're trying to get an element in position 10 but array has 10element [0...9]. So, if you specify position [10] in array, compiler points to element 11. Take a look to filteredData or post how you fill it so we can give a look

Comment: i posted complete ArrayAdapter class. here: http://pastebin.com/2JzUWvmV

Comment: what is data ? what is filteredData ?

Comment: filteredData is to search in listview.

Comment: arrayadapter's getCount() value returns 11 before and after deleting items.maybe it can help ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I noticed that ArrayAdapter's getcount method always returns same value, i overrided getCount() method like this, it works.

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return filteredData.size();
}
```

Comment: In my case that was not enough, getItem has to be overriden as well, an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17045297/891479

Comment: Override and return filteredData.size(), main thing to do

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Lesson learned, when we override the filter, then we override the getFilter() AND getCount() method.